# Experiencing major packet loss and timeouts on chat.stackoverflow.com

Tags: support, chat

I've been trying to diagnose the problem in the JavaScript chat room; the transcript is [here](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/12254090#12254090) (the messages from then on, between myself and @OctavianDamiean):

The long and short of it is that I'm getting major packet loss *only* on chat.stackoverflow.com.

When I do a `tracert`, after getting the 3rd latency value on hop 9, it pauses for a few seconds before displaying `67.17.192.54`:

```
C:\Users\DB>tracert chat.stackoverflow.com

Tracing route to chat.stackoverflow.com [198.252.206.29]
over a maximum of 30 hops:

  1    10 ms    12 ms    17 ms  cpc8-know14-2-0-gw.17-2.cable.virginmedia.com [92.238.164.1]
  2    12 ms    11 ms    11 ms  know-geam-1a-ge247.network.virginmedia.net [81.97.115.77]
  3    12 ms    13 ms    11 ms  pres-core-2a-ae10-0.network.virginmedia.net [195.182.178.145]
  4    15 ms    12 ms    12 ms  leed-bb-1c-ae12-0.network.virginmedia.net [213.105.159.193]
  5    12 ms    14 ms    11 ms  leed-bb-1b-ae10-0.network.virginmedia.net [62.253.174.25]
  6    18 ms    15 ms    23 ms  Lag4.ar9.LON3.gblx.net [64.214.128.37]
  7     *       17 ms    16 ms  ae6.scr4.LON3.gblx.net [67.17.106.150]
  8    94 ms    82 ms    84 ms  po3-40G.ar4.NYC1.gblx.net [67.17.108.246]
  9    91 ms   120 ms    83 ms  67.17.192.54
 10    85 ms    83 ms    83 ms  border1.po2-20g-bbnet2.nym008.pnap.net [216.52.95.65]
 11    84 ms    83 ms    86 ms  stackexchange-1.border1.nym008.pnap.net [74.201.252.22]
 12    85 ms    84 ms    83 ms  stackoverflow.com [198.252.206.29]

Trace complete.
```

This time I did the trace, it actually lost a packet on hop 7 too.

The problem seems like it's when I'm on `gblx.net`'s network or when I'm switching from `glbx.net` to `pnap.net`.

Is this a problem with Stack Exchange's servers, or with my ISP?

You can read the full transcript for full info on debugging I've done (including `ping`s showing packet loss).

Any advice much appreciated! Trying to chat is very difficult with constant timeouts.

Comment: [Here is another very recent example of one user having a problem only on a specific SE site](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/11204/main-site-is-working-dreadfully). It's a different site though and not chat.

Comment: @MadScientist That sounds very similar to my problem. I have no problem reaching other American websites; just SO. I'm running Kaspersky IS 2013 if that helps. *Edit:* same problem with Kaspersky disabled.

Comment: Now chat.stackoverflow.com is completely down! http://i.imgur.com/wp4F8vM.png Not coming back online...

Comment: It came back up a few minutes after.